# sql query where timestamp is 15+ days ago

Tags: php, mysql

i have this SQL query:

```
where datetime < DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 15 DAY) order by datetime ASC
```

is this the right query to say where datetime is 15 days or more ago?

Comment: Did....... you try it?

Comment: yes and its not working, i just wondered if there was something obvious i have missed out

Comment: "*its not working*" is not a valid error message in MySQL (and I highly doubt in PHP even though I don't know anything about PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use DATE_SUB instead:

```
where datetime < DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 15 DAY) order by datetime ASC
```

- DATE_ADD "adds" an interval to the date you start from.
- DATE_SUB "subtracts" an interval on the date you start from.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for documentation.